# clojure project build using gradle clojurephant plugin "namespace not found after loading "

Tags: gradle, clojure, gradle-plugin, clojure.spec

I'm trying to build clojure project with gradle build tool using [clojurephant](https://github.com/clojurephant/clojurephant) plugin.

The project is on [github here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-demo)

My build file is -

```
    plugins {
        id 'dev.clojurephant.clojure' version '0.6.0'
        id 'application'
    }

    group 'org.example'
    version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'Clojars'
            url = 'https://repo.clojars.org'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.clojure:clojure:1.10.3'

        testRuntimeOnly 'org.ajoberstar:jovial:0.3.0'

        devImplementation 'org.clojure:tools.namespace:1.1.0'
    }

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

Below is the calc.clj file at dir [src/main/clojure/math](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-demo/blob/master/src/main/clojure/math/calc.clj) dir

```
(ns math.calc)
(defn add [x y] (+ x y))
(defn demo [x y] (* 2 x y))
```

Below is the calc_test.clj at dir [src/test/clojure/math](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-demo/blob/master/src/test/clojure/math/calc_test.clj) dir

```
(ns math.calc)
(defn add [x y] (+ x y))
(defn demo [x y] (* 2 x y))
```

when I run `gradle test`, I get below error -

> $ gradle test
>
> > Task :compileTestClojure FAILED
> > Syntax error compiling at (REPL:2:1).
> > namespace 'math.calc-test' not found after loading '/math/calc_test'
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':compileTestClojure'.
>
> > Compilation failed. See output above.
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
> 2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

What is wrong with my project setup? How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong ns in your test. I must be `(ns math.calc-test)`

Comment: And the next error will be, that there are no tests.

Comment: why do you say there are no tests. After I applied your suggestion, gradle build command is working.

Comment: The code you pasted is most likely a copy-and-paste error but for this error it's the same. The code there has no deftest etc. Yet on the other hand I never used gradle to build/run tests for clojure so maybe this all just fine (but i really dont see how having two functions there would give you anything but "0 tests run -> no errors")